# Need to fetch user current details from server

Tags: java, android, json, android-location

I'm new to android location part but did the userA current location posting to the server, but facing quite a bit problem in fetching back the userA location and showing it in userB screen.

What i have done is I'm using the Volley library to fetch the location from the server and posting it in the onMapReady method by auto refreshing the page every 1 sec, but its giving a null pointer exception as 
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference.

If my approach is wrong, could you please help me out suggesting one?

This is the code i have implemented in my project

```
private void fetchLocation(){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constant.LocationTrackingURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("resp");
                            for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                newLatitude = jsonObject.getString("loc_latitude").trim();
                                newLongitude = jsonObject.getString("loc_longitude").trim();
                                Toast.makeText(MapAct.this, newLatitude+", "+newLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                addmarkerToMap(newLatitude, newLongitude);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                queue.add(request);
            }
        }, 1000);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                Double lat = Double.parseDouble(newLatitude);
                Double lng = Double.parseDouble(newLongitude);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I'm here"));
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(17).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });
    }

    private void addmarkerToMap(String newLat, String newLng){
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(newLat);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(newLng);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Locations are getting posted as latitude : "+lat+", longitude : "+lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("I'm Here");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
```

Comment: your `jsonObject.getString()` is returning `null`. Are you sure the key for the `JSONObject` is correct?

Comment: Please add your JSON response. This will help to find out.

Comment: this is my response from server "status": true,
    "resp": [
        {
            "loc_latitude": "12.277751",
            "loc_longitude": "76.6146748"
        }
    ]

Comment: it looks like your JSON is correctly parsed. I think the `"loc_latitude"` you are receiving is `null`. Can you check your `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);` and see what key-values you get (using the debugger)